# Python3: Why is my else statement activating regardless of multiple if statements being true

Tags: python

```
tweet = ''
tweet = input('Enter a tweet (160 characters or less):\n')

if len(tweet) <= 160:
    if 'LOL' in tweet:
        print('Laugh out loud')
    if 'BFN' in tweet:
        print('Bye for now')
    if 'BRB' in tweet:
        print('Be right back')
    if 'IRL' in tweet:
        print('In real life')
    if 'FTW' in tweet:
        print('For the win')
    if 'LMFAO' in tweet:
        print('Laugh my F**king a** off')
    if 'LMAO' in tweet:
        print('Laugh my a** off')
    else:
        print('You didn\'t use any abbreviations')
elif len(tweet) == 0:
    print('Wow, such empty')
elif len(tweet) > 160:
    print('Your tweet is over 160 characters')
```

So, for example if I run this program and input: 
LOL BRB

The output is: 
Laugh out loud
Be right back
You didn't use any abbreviations

Whereas the output I want for that input is:
Laugh out loud
Be right back

As far as I can tell the indentation is correct. Also we haven't gone over the 'break' or 'enumerate' functions, so we are not expected to use these to attain the desired result.

Thank you for the help!!

This is the code in working order after everyone's help:

```
tweet = ''
tweet = input('Enter a tweet (160 characters or less):\n')

tweet_abbrev = False

if len(tweet) <= 160:
    if 'LOL' in tweet:
        tweet_abbrev = True
        print('Laugh out loud')
    if 'BFN' in tweet:
        tweet_abbrev = True
        print('Bye for now')
    if 'BRB' in tweet:
        tweet_abbrev = True
        print('Be right back')
    if 'IRL' in tweet:
        tweet_abbrev = True
        print('In real life')
    if 'FTW' in tweet:
        tweet_abbrev = True
        print('For the win')
    if 'LMFAO' in tweet:
        tweet_abbrev = True
        print('Laugh my F**king a** off')
    if 'LMAO' in tweet:
        tweet_abbrev = True
        print('Laugh my a** off')
    if not tweet_abbrev:
        print('You didn\'t use any abbreviations')
if len(tweet) == 0:
    print('Wow, such empty')
elif len(tweet) > 160:
    print('Your tweet is over 160 characters')
```

Thank you everyone for the quick responses!!!

Comment: I think you meant most of them to be elif...

Comment: The `else` is only attached to the last `if` statement, not the first ones.

Comment: That should likely be `if`, then `elif`, `elif`, ... `else`

Comment: How would I attach the else statement to all of the if statements? And if I use elif will the program not stop after the first true elif statement?

Comment: When I use elif and the input is LOL FTW it only prints Laugh out loud instead of both abbreviations

Comment: check my answer @Drkdeibs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your last `if` statement does a check and defaults to "You didn't use any abbreviations" if it isn't true.

You don't want all your statements to be `elif` because then it will only resolve to the first check that is true. You want to check them all individually and print the corresponding statement if it is true.

You're just missing one thing: the check that sees if your string doesn't use any abbreviations. Try this.

```
tweet = ''
tweet = input('Enter a tweet (160 characters or less):\n')

if len(tweet) <= 160:
    if 'LOL' in tweet:
        print('Laugh out loud')
    if 'BFN' in tweet:
        print('Bye for now')
    if 'BRB' in tweet:
        print('Be right back')
    if 'IRL' in tweet:
        print('In real life')
    if 'FTW' in tweet:
        print('For the win')
    if 'LMFAO' in tweet:
        print('Laugh my F**king a** off')
    if 'LMAO' in tweet:
        print('Laugh my a** off')
    if {Insert check to see if there are any abbreviations}:
        print('You didn\'t use any abbreviations')
elif len(tweet) == 0:
    print('Wow, such empty')
elif len(tweet) > 160:
    print('Your tweet is over 160 characters')
```

And just replace `{Insert check to see if there are any abbreviations}` with a valid check. To try it out immediately, you can just do `if '\'' in tweet:`

Comment: Your answer is definitely what I need to do. But I can't think of a way to check to see if there are any abbreviations. I'm not trying to have ya'll do this for me, but it's not even for credit and I really want to understand what I'm doing. Been beating my head against the wall with this one.

Comment: @Drkdeibs Just add `abbreviations=0` at the start of the loop, `abbreviations += 1` in each `if` statement, and check if `abbreviations = 0` at the last `if`. This way you can also keep track of how many abbreviations are in each string.

Comment: You have 2 options that I know of. You can either use a regular expression to check for that (read this post for help: https://superuser.com/questions/1182049/regular-expression-to-find-abbreviations), or you can use a package that uses natural language processing to help you out with that. I've used https://spacy.io/ in the past and it's really great.

Comment: Thank you! I understand that and it works!! :)

Comment: @Drkdeibs awesome! Happy to help! Please accept this as the correct answer if it might be useful for people in the future :)

Comment: Cheking FOR abbreviations and keeping track of the number of them allows me to output a statement if there are none

Comment: @AlecDonaldMather You're really suggesting an NLP package for a code that consists of 6 if statements? You're welcome OP, Alec I suggest you read my comment again because it is not that hard to understand. Ignore the loop.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood @Ahmet, I actually had the wrong impression of what he meant by "abbreviations." I thought he meant things like "can't" "won't" or "isn't". Which I realize now are "contractions." That's my bad. Also, I was just confused by the fact that you suggested a loop in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is the following:

```
tweet = ''
tweet = input('Enter a tweet (160 characters or less):\n')

if len(tweet) <= 160:
    abbr_found = False
    for (abbr, feedback) in [
        ('LOL', 'Laugh out loud'),
        ('BFN', 'Bye for now'),
        ('BRB', 'Be right back'),
        ('IRL', 'In real life'),
        ('FTW', 'For the win'),
        ('LMFAO', 'Laugh my F**king a** off'),
        ('LMAO', 'Laugh my a** off'),
    ]:
        if abbr in tweet:
            print(feedback)
            abbr_found = True
    if not abbr_found:
        print('You didn\'t use any abbreviations')
elif len(tweet) == 0:
    print('Wow, such empty')
elif len(tweet) > 160:
    print('Your tweet is over 160 characters')
```

For every abbreviation you check, you can get a feedback "translating" to human-speak. If *no abbreviation was used*, you get a feedback indicating this.

I'm making an assumption on the logic you want here, and the easiest way to implement it is using this loop. Otherwise, in addition to the multitude of `if` statements, you would have has to assign to `addr_found` in each of the conditional blocks.

Comment: Just noticed your answer. Very concise and works like a charm. Can you tell me the name of the method you are using to lay out the pairs? It doesn't appear to be a dictionary and I don't think we've covered the method you are using, but it greatly interests me.

Comment: The abbreviation/feedback pairs are laid out as a `list` of 2-`tuple`s of `str`ings. As you can see, adding new abbreviations and feedbacks can now be done in one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of how many `if` conditions were satisfied and at the end, instead of using `else`, check if that number of satisfied conditions is greater than 0. If not, you didn't use any abbreviations.

Alternatively, you could use a boolean or something, that's up to you.

Edit: the uncommented code is for boolean, and the comments show how you could do the same thing with a counter.

```py
x = input("enter numbers")

# number_of_numbers = 0
valid_number = False

if "1" in x:
    valid_number = True
    # number_of_numbers += 1
    print("1")
if "2" in x:
    valid_number = True
    # number_of_numbers += 1
    print("2")
...

# if not number_of_numbers:
if not valid_number:
    print("You didn't use any numbers")
```

Comment: This seems like it would work, but I'm uncertain of how to do that. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: @Drkdeibs updated

Comment: This is what I ended up going with. Thank you all for your help; now I know multiple ways to do what I was trying to accomplish. Ya'll rock!!

Answer (score 0):

This else consider only last if statement. If you want it to consider all, use elif instead.

EDIT: in this case your program will end after first true statement. If you want to check it for all words in tweet, use

```
words = tweet.split()
```

And execute the code (with elifs) for every word in a for loop.

Comment: this doesn't work because OP wants `Laugh out loud Be right back` to be a viable print output which isn't possible with universal `elif`'s

Comment: This! elif stops after the first true statement

Comment: Right! I edited, now should be fine.

Comment: using a for loop feels inefficient/not clean

Answer (score 0):

I would change those `if...if...if...else` to `if..elif...elif...else`. There may be some logic error going on.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, there can be both "BRB" and "LOL" in tweet and with `elif` both would not be checked for.

Answer (score 0):

I know it may be not so efficient, but you may initialize a `flag`

```
tweet = ''
tweet = input('Enter a tweet (160 characters or less):\n')
flag = 0
if len(tweet) <= 160:
    if 'LOL' in tweet:
        print('Laugh out loud')
        flag = 1;
    if 'BFN' in tweet:
        print('Bye for now')
        flag = 1;
    if 'BRB' in tweet:
        print('Be right back')
        flag = 1;
    if 'IRL' in tweet:
        print('In real life')
        flag = 1;
    if 'FTW' in tweet:
        print('For the win')
        flag = 1;
    if 'LMFAO' in tweet:
        print('Laugh my F**king a** off')
        flag = 1;
    if 'LMAO' in tweet:
        print('Laugh my a** off')
        flag = 1;
    elif flag==0:
        print('You didn\'t use any abbreviations')
elif len(tweet) == 0:
    print('Wow, such empty')
elif len(tweet) > 160:
    print('Your tweet is over 160 characters')
```